# c# best events for checking a string(email address) and not lost a focus in that cell if it's not meet certain conditions in dataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

What is the best or appropriate events for checking a certain string like email address. String with this minimum requirements. Example `emailAddress=stack@overflow.us`. I tried `cellValidated` and `cellEndEdit` but it loses focus after checking the string. What i need is that; 
`emailAddress.Contains("@")`
`emailAddress.Contains(".")`
`emailAddress.Length>=5`..etc.

It should not loses focus at the cell if some of the requirements are not meet.

Comment: Not an answer but there's [a better way to validate an email address](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/11/26/validate-mail-address-format-the-easy-way/)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to wire up the `DataGridView_CellValidating` event for this. It could work as such… the user enters some text into the email column… when the user tries to “leave” the cell, the `CellValidating` event will fire. It is here we check to see if the cell being validated is in the “Email” column. If it IS and is a valid email address, then, nothing happens and we continue. If however, the text is NOT a valid email address, then a message box is displayed indicating the invalid email address. Then after the user closes the message box… they will be “forced” to either enter a “valid” email address into the cell OR in this case, enter an empty cell to continue.

To validate the email can be done numerous ways, the link Zohar provided is one way to validate the address and will require using the `System.Net.Mail` library. There is also another method from MS that uses regular expressions and works well… [How to verify that strings are in valid email format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-verify-that-strings-are-in-valid-email-format)

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e) {
  if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Email") {
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.FormattedValue.ToString())) {
      if (!EmailIsValid(e.FormattedValue.ToString())) {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid email address: " + e.FormattedValue.ToString());
        e.Cancel = true;
      }
    }
  }
}

public bool EmailIsValid(string emailaddress) {
  try {
    MailAddress m = new MailAddress(emailaddress);
    return true;
  }
  catch (FormatException) {
    return false;
  }
}
```